# Specify correct dtypes to pandas.read_csv for datetimes and booleans

Tags: python, pandas, csv, types, type-conversion

I am loading a csv file into a Pandas DataFrame. For each column, how do I specify what type of data it contains using the `dtype` argument?

- I can do it with **numeric** data (code at bottom)...
- But how do I specify **time** data...
- and **categorical** data such as factors or booleans? I have tried `np.bool_` and `pd.tslib.Timestamp` without luck.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv(<file-name>, dtype={'A': np.int64, 'B': np.float64})
```

Comment: Have a look at the date_parser-arguments [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html). Regarding the boolen value: How is your data stored? The NumPy [Docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html#id1) state the ```np.bool_``` is for boolean stored as bytes (maybe you are using strings instead?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a lot of options for read_csv which will handle all the cases you mentioned.  You might want to try dtype={'A': datetime.datetime}, but often you won't need dtypes as pandas can infer the types.

**For dates, then you need to specify the parse_date options**:

```
parse_dates : boolean, list of ints or names, list of lists, or dict
keep_date_col : boolean, default False
date_parser : function
```

**In general for converting boolean values you will need to specify:**

```
true_values  : list  Values to consider as True
false_values : list  Values to consider as False
```

Which will transform any value in the list to the boolean true/false.  For more general conversions you will most likely need

converters : dict. optional  Dict of functions for converting values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column labels

Though dense, check here for the full list: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

Comment: Did not know about the converters. Will look into that. But what about categories specified as integers? In my case I have a lot of those features, and since they are neither ordinal, interval or ratio it would by nice to be able to specify them as nominal (categorical).

Comment: If the categorical data is strings, then leave them as strings and convert to ints after reading in the DataFrame (or you could use the converters to convert specific columns).  If you have int like categories, then couldn't you just read them in as int data types?

Comment: The data IS integers, but they should be treated as categories. Otherwise many machine learning models will use these features in a wrong way.

Comment: I follow you.  My comment is you can do the conversion as you are reading in the CSV or you can do the conversion after you have the DataFrame.  Personally I think the latter is a little easier.  After reading in the Dataframe, let's say you want to make column 'A' categorical.  Have a little mapping: def MapA(int1):  if int1==0: return 'category1' elif int1==1: return 'category2' etc... and make a new column of categorical data