# dtype specification at initialization of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion, runtime-error

I am having a problem with dtypes when initializing a DataFrame. If I give only one type, it wolks, if I give an array, it doesn't work. I get this message :

> TypeError: data type not understood

While I think I read examples with arrays.
Here is a little module that shows my problem.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 2], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print df
'''
   one  two
a    1    1
b    2    2
c    2    3
d  NaN    4
'''
#  works ok

df = pd.DataFrame(d, dtype=float)
print df
'''
   one  two
a    1    1
b    2    2
c    2    3
d  NaN    4
'''
#  works ok

df = pd.DataFrame(d, dtype=str)
print df
'''
   one  two
a  1.0  1.0
b  2.0  2.0
c  2.0  3.0
d  NaN  4.0

'''
#  works ok

df = pd.DataFrame(d, dtype=[str,float,float])
print df
'''
TypeError: data type not understood
'''
```

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like this may not be implemented or documented very well, but there are other ways to do the same thing:  Take a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197774/assign-pandas-dataframe-column-dtypes

Comment: Thank you John, but I think this doesn't meet my need. The next step will be to decide for my actual DataFrame, different types for each column. In my example here, the workaround consisting in applying numeric type to each column would be equivalent, I agree, but if I want to save integers as float and strings on different columns, I think I will need a way to give a array of formats (or a dictionnary)... Or maybe I'm missing the simple yet brilliant idea? :)

Comment: when reading a CSV:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095983/specify-correct-dtypes-using-pandas-read-csv