# varchar values are getting stored as decimals

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, mysql-workbench

I have created a SQL table, which has an "ID" column of type **varchar (10)**

Now, when I am parsing and loading a CSV file into this table, the ID column values (1,2,3,4,5,.....) are getting stored as (1.0,2.0,.3.0,.4.0,.5.0,.....).

I m not able to infer why all the IDs are getting converted to decimal when the column type is set to Varchar in SQL, and how can this be avoided?

Table's create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE INFO (
    AsOfDate DATE NOT NULL,
    Employee_ID VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    Emlpoyee_Name VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    Emlpoyee_Designation VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    KEY IDX1_INFO(Employee_ID)
    ) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

The CSV file looks like this:

```
20180215, 1, John, Data Analyst  
20180215, 2, Alex, Full Stack Developer  
20180215, 3, Paul, Senior Manager 
.  
.  
.
```

To parse the file, I use simple Pandas logic:

```
df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/csv/file/")
```

P.S.: I can't declare column type as Int because there are some ids like A1, B7, etc.

Comment: what does the csv look like, and how are you parsing it?

Comment: Are you storing your csv directly or by some sort of select from another table? Could you give us the create statement of the table?

Comment: The real question is "How are you loading it?". If you target column is a varchar(10) and your source data is clearly an integer, then somewhere in your load the data is being transformed. So... how are you loading it? And, also, what is happening to your `ID` of `A1` and `B7`. during this load. Do they gain a decimal too?

Comment: I seriously doubt the CSV file has the decimals.  It is almost certainly the code that is reading it.

Comment: @JNevill No, A1, B7 are loaded as it is

Comment: I think we need to see your insert statement/procedure to help, if you are really sending "1" in as a string there would be no reason to end up with 1.0 unless some intermediary transformation has happened.

Comment: @xCloudx8 here is the create statement  

CREATE TABLE `INFO` (  
  `AsOfDate` date NOT NULL,  
  `Employee_ID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `Emlpoyee_Name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `Emlpoyee_Designation` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,  
  KEY `IDX1_INFO` (`Employee_ID`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: can you add loading step in the question?

Comment: CSV FILE looks like this  

20180215, 1, John, Data Analyst  
20180215, 2, Alex, Full Stack Developer  
20180215, 3, Paul, Senior Manager 
.  
.  
.  
.  



Parsing logic is also very simple - (using pandas library):  
**df = pd.read_csv(/path/to/csv/file/)**

Comment: So as you read the csv in python are you taking the datatype to a variable?  if so what is that variables datatype?  our guess is that in python the read from the csv is casting (implicitly most likely) to a decimal datatype. That type is causing the insert to to occur  with the .0 into a varchar field which accepts the decimal value and implicitly casts it to varchar leaving the  .0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify correct dtypes using pandas.read\_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095983/specify-correct-dtypes-using-pandas-read-csv)

Comment: I've added `python` and `pandas` as tags here since this feels very much like the solution is in the `read_csv()` function of `pandas`. Specifically the `dtype` and `converters` parameters listed in the pandas `read_csv` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: Yes, you are right.   


When I execute **print df["Employee_ID"]**, the output Series says **Name: Employee_ID, dtype: float64**  




I need to convert it to String. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the help from [JNevill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221001/jnevill), [xQbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016435/xqbert) and [SChowdhury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4956362/schowdhury), I figured out that it was just a matter of adding one line to my Python Code, before loading data into the database:

```
df['Employee_ID'] = df['Employee_ID'].astype('object')
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
  temp=u"""a,b,c,d
    2,2,2,2.0"""
    #after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                     dtype={'a': int, 'b': float}, 
                     converters={'c': D.Decimal, 'd': D.Decimal})
print (df)
   a    b  c    d
0  2  2.0  2  2.0

for i, v in df.iterrows():
    print(type(v.a), type(v.b), type(v.c), type(v.d))
```