# Saving data types for a pandas dataframe saved as a csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I want to be able to save dtypes for my df and when I next time read csv I want to prove an array of dtypes.

I tried the following:

```
types_dic = df.dtypes.to_dict()
np.save("dtypes.npy", types_dic, allow_pickle=True)
dtyp = np.load("dtypes.npy", allow_pickle=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv(join(folder_no_extension, file), dtype=dtyp)
```

But it does not work --datetime time is not restored...

it also does not work if I create dictionary explicitly

```
types_dic = {}
for t in df.dtypes:
   types_dic[t] = str(df.dtypes[t])



df.dtypes

BN                            object
School_Year           datetime64[ns]
Start_Date            datetime64[ns]
Overall_Rating                object
Indicator_1.1                 object
Indicator_1.2                 object
Indicator_1.3                 object
Indicator_1.4                 object
```

and

```
df2.dtypes

BN                    object
School_Year           object
Start_Date            object
Overall_Rating        object
Indicator_1.1         object
Indicator_1.2         object
Indicator_1.3         object
Indicator_1.4         object
```

Comment: have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095983/specify-correct-dtypes-to-pandas-read-csv-for-datetimes-and-booleans

Comment: Look at `dtyp` after `load`.  It probably is an array containing a dict, not a dict itself.  Use `pickle` if you want to save a dictionary without that array wrapper.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, *if you don't have to* save your results as a csv file you can instead use pandas methods like [`to_pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) or [`to_parquet`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html) which will preserve the column data types.

Secondly, *if you do want to save your results in a csv* format and preserve their data types then [you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269399/datetime-dtypes-in-pandas-read-csv) the `parse_dates` argument of [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). To do that you could update to be:

```
    # Save non-date dtypes
    non_date_dict = df.dtypes[df.dtypes != '<M8[ns]'].to_dict()
    np.save("non_date_dict.npy", non_date_dict, allow_pickle=True)
    non_date_dict2 = np.load("non_date_dict.npy", allow_pickle=True)
    # Save date dtypes
    date_col_list = list(df.dtypes[df.dtypes == '<M8[ns]'].index)
    np.save("date_col_list.npy", date_col_list, allow_pickle=True)
    date_col_list2 = np.load("date_col_list.npy", allow_pickle=True)
    # Load
    df2 = pd.read_csv('pandas_dtypes.csv',
                      dtype=non_date_dict2,
                      parse_dates=list(date_col_list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer with what worked for me. It's probably not the prettiest solution, but it works. Might as well help someone

```
import json
...
dic = {}
for t in df.dtypes.to_dict():
    dic[t] = str(df.dtypes[t])

with open('dtypes.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(dic, fp)

with open('dtypes.json', 'r') as fp:
    dtyp = json.load(fp)

dic = {}
dates = []

for t in dtyp:
    if "object" in str(dtyp[t]):
        atype = np.str
    elif "float" in str(dtyp[t]):
        atype = np.float_
    elif "datetime" in str(dtyp[t]):
        atype = np.str
        dates.append(t)
    else:
        atype = np.int_
    dic[t] = atype

df2 = pd.read_csv(path, dtype=dic, parse_dates=dates)
```