# Read quoted fields in CSV as strings (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

### Context

I have a pandas dataframe which I need to save to disk and re-load later. Because the file saved on disk needs to be human-readable, I'm currently saving the dataframe as a CSV. The data includes values that are integers, booleans, null/`None`, timestamps, and strings.

### Problem

Some of the string values are phone numbers, formatted as `"+12025550140"`, but these are being converted to integers by the round trip (dataframe -> CSV -> dataframe). I need them to stay as strings.

I've changed the CSV writing portion to use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`, which preserves the format of the phone numbers into the CSV, but when they are read back into a dataframe they are converted to integers. If I tell the CSV reading portion to also use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`, then they are converted to floats.

How do I enforce that quoted fields are loaded as strings? Or, is there any other way to enforce that the full process is type-safe?

### Constraints and non-constraints

The file saved to disk must be easy to manually edit, preferably with a plain text editor. I have full control and ownership over the code which generates the CSV file. A different file format can be used if it is easy to apply manual edits.

### Code

Writing to disk:

```py
import csv

df = get_df()  # real function has been replaced
df.to_csv(query_file_path, index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Reading from disk:

```py
import pandas as pd

CSV_NA_VALS = pd._libs.parsers.STR_NA_VALUES
CSV_NA_VALS.remove("")

df = pd.read_csv(query_file_path, na_values=CSV_NA_VALS)
df = df.replace([""], [None])
```

#### Versions

- Python 3.9.5
- pandas==1.4.0

Comment: I suspect you need to use the `dtype` option to `read_csv` to force that column to be a string.

Comment: Manually selecting the columns to be read as strings? I suppose I can make that work, but this code is used on tables with varying schemas. It'll get messy finding/specifying all of the variously named columns that contain phone numbers.

Comment: Providing a tiny portion of data definitely would help for accurate/complete answer!

Comment: If you have values that look numeric but must be treated as strings, there's no way for pandas to know that if you don't tell it.

Comment: One option might be to pickle a dictionary of your dataframe's `dtypes` separately from your csv, then unpickle and use it when you `read` it in again

Comment: @Barmar I'd think pandas would be able to differentiate between strings that look numeric vs actually numeric values by the presence of quotes in the CSV. I guess not, though

Comment: @G.Anderson that seems like a more complete workaround, thanks

Comment: Depends on what your data looks like by could try is_numeric_dtype(). Else maybe this answer will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829190/saving-data-types-for-a-pandas-dataframe-saved-as-a-csv

Comment: @rkechols Some CSVs quote all the fields, so pandas doesn't use quotes as a type indicator. It could be a possible option, but as far as I can tell it doesn't have that capability.