# df.to_csv adds extra decimal to a object type column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, floating-point, export-to-csv

I am trying to write a dataframe to csv using df.to_csv.
I read the data using read_excel and all columns are read as dtype=object.

```
df = pf.read_excl(f, dtype=str)
df.head()
```

[image]

```
df.to_csv(new_file )
```

[image]

Here the value 272.16 is being written as 272.15999... in the csv file.
How do I avoid this? I want the value to be written as it is in the dataframe.

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829190/saving-data-types-for-a-pandas-dataframe-saved-as-a-csv

Comment: The value in your dataframe is `272.15999999999997`, it's only the default formatting that displays it as `272.16`. The easiest way to reproduce the default console output format with csv is something like `with open(new_file, 'w') as f:`  `df.to_string()`. Alternatively you can specify a float format in [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)

Comment: The value is 272.16 in the input file as well.